# Definition of Cascade for Blockciphers

Tags: block-cipher, notation

I have seen that given blockciphers $F,G : \mathcal{K} \times \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$, their cascade $F \circ G$ is defined to be $F \circ G : \mathcal{K}^2 \times \mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{M}$ via $(F \circ G)_{(K,K')}(M) = G_{K'}(F_K(M))$. My question is why it's done this way around, not the other order?

In "standard life" (see [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)), if I have two functions $f,g : X \to X$, then $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$. However above, writing $f = F_K$ and $g = G_{K'}$, we have, in essence, $(f \circ g)(m) = g(f(m))$.

I understand that it's just a formal convention, but it seems strange to pick the formal convention which is (or rather, appears to me to be) counter to the previously established convention.

Incidentally, I saw this notation in [Hoang-Morris-Rogaway](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1176), twice on page 6.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not standard in cryptography, but I guess some authors define $(f \circ g)(x) = g(f(x))$ rather than $f(g(x))$. This is also mentioned in a footnote on Wikipedia.

Comment: Ok, fair enough! I did wonder if that might be the case, but I'm very new to crypto, so didn't want to assume! That said, I'm doing a maths PhD currently and I've never seen anyone *actually* use $(f \circ g)(x) = g(f(x))$. When I learned about these things in first year, I was told that some do, but I guess I'd just come to think that no-one *really* did, certainly not in the mainstream. Looks like maybe I'm wrong! (Note that Morris is a probabilist by trade, like myself, not a compsci. Obviously we can crossover though!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's at the authors discretion. See the footnote in the book (below). Also Wikipedia [makes it clear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

[image: function composition]:

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what you said was actually already covered in the comments :) -- interesting, though, to see a group theory(?) book that uses that convention; as in the comments, in all my (not that many) years, I've never actually come across an example (until now!)